# correct way to handle back event for the updated list in react native

Tags: react-native, back, react-virtualized

I have been implementing a passbookView, where we fetch the transaction list from the backend.

and user can navigate to a detailView for each transaction where he can cancel the transaction.

now the issue is when user cancel the transaction and presses back button from detailView, he will be navigated to passbookView where the status of the transaction is not changed as list was fetched from backend before cancellation.

I have used isFocued to fetch transaction list everytime passbookView is focused
it did solved the issue

but is this the correct way to handle this situation.

Comment: The use of isFocused to fetch data in the passbookView when it regains focus is a functional solution for maintaining data consistency. However, it may have performance implications, as it could lead to unnecessary network requests. Consider alternative approaches such as data caching or using a state management library for more efficient data handling.